# API upload to YouTube, how to set age restriction?

Tags: php, youtube-data-api

As the title says, I'm trying to set age restriction on a video I'm uploading with the API.  I have created Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet and Google_Service_YouTube_Video objects.  If anyone could suggest how I could do this, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Could you provide some code and tell us what you tried so far? The services names doesn´t help without code

Comment: I haven't tried anything as I couldn't find any reference to it in the docs.